# How to send messages between 2 chrome tabs (from different origins) without a server or an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing my web app in React on Chrome.

I have tried...

1. To get a reference of the Window object of one tab from the other tab,
   but I can do this only if I use `window.open()` witch opens a new tab and I need to get a reference to an existing tab.
   Also changing window.name and then `window.open('', 'windowName')` didn't help.
   Maybe there is a way to get the Window reference of an existing tab without opening a new one?
2. To open a UDP socket but I failed to (I think it is not possible on Chrome).
3. To open a TCP socket, but it requires a TCP server witch as far as I read, chrome client can't open one.
4. Local storage is shareable only between tabs from same origin (or aren't they?).

Comment: You are SOL. No way your browser based code can do what you want UNLESS they BOTH can access the same server. They CANNOT access the same cookie or windowStorage

Comment: You can do something stupid like an embedded iframe with a url like https://mysecondsite/?args=to&pass=foo and have it store it to the local storage so that the original page can pick it up.

Comment: You can also use `Window.postMessage()` across two different domains, but you would need to own and have control of both domains to set it up. Same with the first alternative I mentioned. However, if you're trying to control someone else's website through your website. Its not possible due to security measures.